# Import .csv file at openproject

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, openproject, eruby

When i try to import .csv file i get the following error message.

> ```
> NoMethodError in Users1#index 
> undefined method `project' for #<AnonymousUser:0x00000005737b98>
> ```

MY `users1_controller.rb`

```
class Users1Controller < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users1 = User.all 
  end

  def import
    User.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Activity Data imported!" 
  end
end
```

MY index.html.erb

```
    <h1>Users1#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users1/index.html.erb</p>
<%= flash[:notice] %>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Projects</th>
<th>Task ID</th>
<th>Tasks</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @users1.each do |user| %>
<tr>
<td><%= user.project %></td>
<td><%= user.task_id %></td>
<td><%= user.task %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>

<h4>Import that data!</h4>
<%= form_tag import_users_path, multipart: true do %>
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
<%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by asking whether you are using a single table for User and AnonymousUser. Does Anonymous User respond to `:project`?